# About #include mechanism in c++

Tags: c++

Recently I run into some strange code, this is definitely a bad practice but kinda interesting.

For example, I have three files:
something.h

```
class Something  
{  
    void func();  
}
```

something.cpp

```
void Something::func()  
{  
    #define STRANGE() //do something  
    #include strange.h  
    return;  
}
```

strange.h

```
STRANGE()
```

That `STRANGE()` called in strange.h actually runs!

This makes me curious about the include mechanism, is the `#include` derivative simply take everything in the included file and put them at the `#include` before compiling?

If that’s true, I can even switch the role of .cpp and .h, declaring in cpp files while implementing in h files.

Comment: What do you mean by "it runs?" Would you mind including your code from your `main.cpp`?

Comment: *This makes me curious about the include mechanism, is the #include derivative simply take everything in the included file and put them at the #include before compiling?*. Yes.

Comment: The extensions *.cpp and *.h are merely convention. You can also make them all *.txt files if you want.

Comment: For starters, `#include strange.h` is invalid. You need either `"..."` or `<...>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do C++ header files work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844199/how-do-c-header-files-work)

Comment: STRANGE() , is defined , but assigned to nothing. so what is the point in worrying about it? wouldn't that  be replacing the expression with nothing?

Comment: This technique is used in [X macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) btw. Bad practice or not, I once had to use it to keep certain parts of my production code maintainable after having failed to find a better (aka. more C++-ish) replacement for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per C++ standard ([[cpp.include]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.include#3)):

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # include " q-char-sequence " new-line
> ```
>
> causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the specified
> sequence between the " delimiters. The named source file is searched for in an implementation-defined
> manner. If this search is not supported, or if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read
>
> ```
> # include < h-char-sequence > new-line
> ```
>
> with the identical contained sequence (including > characters, if any) from the original directive.

So the answer to your question:

> This makes me curious about the include mechanism, is the #include derivative simply take everything in the included file and put them at the #include before compiling?

Is simply "yes".

About naming of the files, as someone already pointed out in the comments, extensions are just part of the filename. They do not play any role in the interpretation of a file by the C++ compiler. As such, you can name them absolutely whatever you want. You can even not include an extension, as the STL does.

Comment: A note concerning _implementation-defined manner_: If I place a relative path in an `#include ""` in a header (which is subject of pre-processing itself) I always ask myself if the current directory is the folder of that header or of the translation unit where pre-processing started for. From my impression, MSVC and g++ do the former but I would appreciate if this would be more precisely defined...

Answer (score 0):

Yes the include directive simply copies the included file and replaces the directive.

Yes you can include .cpp files, .c files and files with no extensions (like most headers in standard library now).

The extension is just for the programmer and maybe for IDE (which may generate makefile or compiler command line arguments according to extension)